# Post photo into facebook album with php

Tags: php

I'm trying to post a photo from an URL into my FB and after reading and reading I was not able to make it work. Here is my code, which I took on the web:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$app_id = "316094425259906";
$app_secret = "1610877d611967f77ba4e677c851eb75";
$my_url = "http://www.cdn-coins.com/CCDatabase/eng/fb7.php"; // mainly, redirect to this page
$perms_str = "publish_stream";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];


if(empty($code)) {
$auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&scope=" . $perms_str;
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
}


$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
. $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);


$p = null;
parse_str($response, $p);
$access_token = $p['access_token'];
$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
     . "access_token=" .$access_token;




if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$params = array();
if( isset($_POST['message']) ) {
    $params['message'] = trim($_POST['message']);
}

$uploaddir = './uploads/'; // Upload folder
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['source']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['source']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $params['source'] = "@" . realpath($uploadfile);
}

// Start the Graph API call
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$graph_url);

/*
    Next option is only used for 
    user from a local (WAMP) 
    machine. This should be removed
    when used on a live server!
    refer:https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/7
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
curl_close($ch);
if(is_array($decoded) && isset($decoded['id'])) {
    /*
        Picture is uploaded successfully:
        1) show success message
        2) optionally, delete image from our server
    */
    $msg = "Image uploaded successfully: {$decoded['id']}";
}
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload</title>
<style>
label {float: left; width: 100px;}
input[type=text],textarea {width: 210px;}
#msg {border: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px; color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($msg) ) { ?>
<p id="msg"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
<p><label for="name">Caption</label><input type="text" name="message" value="" /></p>
<p><label for="source">Photo</label><input type="file" name="source" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It supposed to load the photo, but it doesnt and I dont have the $msg a the ned, nothing.

Thanks for helping me.